# Data.Text vs String

Tags: string, haskell, text

While the general opinion of the Haskell community seems to be that it's always better to use `Text` instead of `String`, the fact that still the APIs of most of maintained libraries are `String`-oriented confuses the hell out of me. On the other hand, there are [notable projects](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/basic-prelude), which consider `String` as a mistake altogether and provide a `Prelude` with all instances of `String`-oriented functions replaced with their `Text`-counterparts.

So are there any reasons for people to keep writing `String`-oriented APIs except backwards- and standard Prelude-compatibility and the "switch-making inertia"?
Are there possibly any other drawbacks to `Text` as compared to `String`?

Particularly, I'm interested in this because I'm designing a library and trying to decide which type to use to express error messages.

Comment: How hard will it be to support both?

Comment: String is easy to use, but Text is efficient. 
I say, efficiency is a compiler problem, because its the compilers job to optimize. Take a programmer to write a faster lib just means that the compiler isn't good enough. (sadly, we don't have really good compilers)

Comment: @Vektorweg I'd argue. Since `String` is just an alias for a list of `Char`s, it's natural that it has different performance characteristics from a monolithic data, which `Text` is. Both types are not at all of compiler's concern, since they aren't primitive and are defined in libraries.

Comment: @DanielWagner Wouldn't it turn to be a not much motivated complication? Anyway, the question is about a general approach, if there was a shared pattern of supporting both types throughout libraries that would be considerable.

Comment: @Vektorweg There's a good blog post about the [Sufficiently Smart Compiler](http://prog21.dadgum.com/40.html). (I just now realised it mentions GHC as well.)

Comment: Go for Text ! Future generations may one day benefit from a String-free world if we stop adding String-dependent code.

Answer (score 35):

My unqualified guess is that most library writers don't want to add more dependencies than necessary. Since strings are part of literally every Haskell distribution (it's part of the language standard!), it is a lot easier to get adopted if you use strings and don't require your users to sort out Text distributions from hackage.

It's one of those "design mistakes" that you just have to live with unless you can convince most of the community to switch over night. Just look at how long it has taken to get Applicative to be a superclass of Monad – a relatively minor but much wanted change – and imagine how long it would take to replace all the String things with Text.

---

To answer your more specific question: I would go with String unless you get noticeable performance benefits by using Text. Error messages are usually rather small one-off things so it shouldn't be a big problem to use String.

On the other hand, if you are the kind of ideological purist that eschews pragmatism for idealism, go with Text.

---

* I put design mistakes in scare quotes because strings as a list-of-chars is a neat property that makes them easy to reason about and integrate with other existing list-operating functions.

Comment: It's not as much about some sorta fanatic purity, it's just that I'd rather contribute to a switch for the better (if it really is one), rather then stagnation of suboptimal approaches. Okay, so you confirm that essentially there's no drawbacks to using Text?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov If you want to contribute to a switch, I think you can make a greater change by involving yourself in the process of updating the standard and lobbying/converting existing libraries. Virtually no drawbacks other than the ones you can think of, such as adoption rate and people wanting to pattern match on the first letter or use map from Data.List and so on.

Comment: That might not matter so much anymore, since Data.Text is pretty much a given today and comes out of the box with GHC (which I assume most people use these days).

Answer (score 25):

If your API is targeted at processing large amounts of character oriented data and/or various encodings, then your API should use **Text**.

If your API is primarily for dealing with small one-off strings, then using the built-in **String** type should be fine.

Using **String** for large amounts of text will make applications using your API consume significantly more memory.  Using it with foreign encodings could seriously complicate usage depending on how your API works.

String is quite expensive (at least 5N words where N is the number of Char in the String).  A word is same number of bits as the processor architecture (ex. 32 bits or 64 bits):
http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/06/memory-footprints-of-some-common-data.html

Comment: I don't think ASCII has anything to do with it: both String and Text equally support Unicode, pushing the actual encoding under your level of abstraction. In both cases, you would only have to worry about it at the borders of your program. Unicode support is not a good criteria to choose between the two.

Comment: You mixed up `String` with `ByteString` concerning the ASCII.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis isn't there the issue that one `Char` in string can be only part of a Unicode character and not a single Unicode character? Won't that cause confusion? Does Data.Text solve this?

Comment: @João Portela: Haskell `Char`s are not like Java or C# `char`s. They are full Unicode code points (32bit).

Comment: They are 32bit? I always assumed they were 16bit. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: On top of @TobiasBrandt's point, the cost of String is more, because there is a cons cell for each list element.  String is actually [Char] which is a List of Char, not an array, so the cost is more like 64-bits per Char (on 32-bit) or 128-bits per Char (on 64-bit) plus 32-bits per list item. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Memory_Footprint

Answer (score 14):

There are at least three reasons to use [Char] in small projects.

1. `[Char]` does not rely on any arcane staff, like foreign pointers, raw memory, raw arrays, etc that may work differently on different platforms or even be unavailable altogether
2. `[Char]` is the lingua franka in haskell. There are at least three 'efficient' ways to handle unicode data in haskell: `utf8-bytestring`, `Data.Text.Text` and `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector Char`, each requiring dealing with extra package.
3. by using `[Char]` one gains access to all power of `[]` monad, including many specific functions (alternative string packages do try to help with it, but still)

Personally, I consider **utf16**-based `Data.Text` one of the most questionable desicions of the haskell community, since **utf16** combines flaws of both **utf8** and **utf32** encoding while having none of their benefits.

Comment: Can you give more info as to why you think utf16 to be inferior? Not necessarily as a part of this answer, but maybe to an article detailing your stance.

Comment: @Wizek - it's a reasonably common opinion.  See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful.

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if Data.Text is always more efficient than Data.String???

"cons" for instance is O(1) for Strings and O(n) for Text. Append is O(n) for Strings and O(n+m) for strict Text's. Likewise,

```
    let foo = "foo" ++ bigchunk
        bar = "bar" ++ bigchunk
```

is more space efficient for Strings than for strict Texts.

Other issue not related to efficiency is pattern matching (perspicuous code) and lazyness (predictably per-character in Strings, somehow implementation dependent in lazy Text).

Text's are obviously good for static character sequences and for in-place modification. For other forms of structural editing, Data.String might have advantages.

Comment: There is more to performance and efficiency than just big oh. The String implementation is a linked list with a node for every single character. That's a lot of extra memory, cache, and fragmentation for a simple string.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think there is a single technical reason for String to remain.
And I can see several ones for it to go.

Overall I would first argue that in the Text/String case there is only one best solution :

- String performances are bad, everyone agrees on that
- Text is not difficult to use. All functions commonly used on String are available on Text, plus some useful more in the context of strings (substitution, padding, encoding)
- having two solutions creates unnecessary complexity unless all base functions are made polymorphic. Proof : there are [SO questions on the subject of automatic conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641847/automatic-conversion-between-string-and-data-text-in-haskell?noredirect=1&lq=1). So this *is* a problem.

So one solution is less complex than two, and the shortcomings of String will make it disappear eventually. The sooner the better !

Comment: It's not really that simple, no. There's a fair bit of non-trivial string-processing code out there that's designed around `String` and wouldn't work at all well with `Text`.

Comment: @dfeuer    I would be very interested in pointers - I sorely lack first-hand experience on those cases.