# benefits of Data.Text

Tags: string, haskell

What are the benefits of importing Data.Text over Haskell's native string functions?

```
ghci$> drop 3 "abcdefg"
     > "defg"
ghci$> import qualified Data.Text as T
     > T.drop 3 $ T.pack "abcdefg" 
     > "defg"
```

etc. many other methods (if not all) that are provided by Data.Text are provided out the box by the standard library. In addition, to use a string with Data.Text, I have to pack/unpack the string into a Text. Why would I want to use Data.Text?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608745/data-text-vs-string

Comment: Naturally, you would want to use `Data.Text` when you *don't* pack/unpack textual data to/from `String`. That happens when you work with external data - and that's what most of programs do.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to pack `Text` explicitly. Just use the `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` extension, then you can write simply `T.drop 3 "abcdefg"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Data.Text` is more space-efficient.  Haskell's native `String` is equivalent to a linked list of `Char`s, which means it has very high space overhead for even moderately-sized chunks of text.

`Data.Text` is generally more performant than `String`.  Because `String` is a linked list, whereas `Text` is a memory array (or several memory arrays in the lazy variant), it provides much better memory locality.  `Text` can usually interface with native system libraries (e.g. IO) much more efficiently than `String`s, which need to go through an intermediate buffer.  For programs that do a lot of IO (reading/writing files), the speedup can be an order of magnitude or more.

Finally, `Data.Text` provides some text-specific functions that aren't readily available with native `String`s.  For example, various case-folding and substring-related functions.  While variants of these that work on `String`s could certainly be provided, there's little incentive to do so since the `Text` versions are readily available.